# How to change FOV on Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I zoom out?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49969/how-do-i-zoom-out)

Its restricted FOV has given me a wicked headache, something I have never got before, not even with Darkness II.

Any fix for the Field Of View for the non steam version?

Pity, its a lovely game.

Comment: Why did you remove field of view as tag? Surely that's what its there for?

Comment: Hi Dino! That is indeed what the tag *was* for. However lately we have been removing some categories of tags, and this tag belonged to one of them. It was now removed from all questions on the site, including yours. If you want more information about this you can visit our [meta] site or our [chat]. In any case it means you tagged well :)

Comment: Dino, just a heads up, the FOV fix I outline in the duplicate question linked here is now compatible with Origin, so give it a try if you'd like a relatively easy fix for FOV.